Angular - Why isn't my dropdown list working
HTML code:
<li class="nav-item dropdown pe-3">
  <a class="nav-link nav-profile d-flex align-items-center pe-0" (click)="toggleProfileMenu()">
    <img src="assets/img/profile-img.jpg" alt="Profile" class="rounded-circle">
    <span class="d-none d-md-block dropdown-toggle ps-2">{{ username  }}</span>
  </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end dropdown-menu-arrow profile" *ngIf="isProfileMenuOpen" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <li class="dropdown-header">
      <h6>{{username}}</h6>
    </li>
    <li>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center">
        <i class="bi bi-gear"></i>
        <span>Account Settings</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <hr class="dropdown-divider">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" (click)="logout()">
        <i class="bi bi-box-arrow-right"></i>
        <span>Sign Out</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

ts code:
@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
isProfileMenuOpen = false;
  

  toggleProfileMenu(): void {
    this.isProfileMenuOpen = !this.isProfileMenuOpen;
  }

When I click on that arrow/triangle, nothing happens. (Expected result: The items of the drop list appear and when you click once again they disappear)

Looks like you are using Bootstrap dropdown? If yes, you don't need programmatically update isProfileMenuOpen variable to show/hide dropdown menu.

@YongShun yes i'm using bootstrap's , how should it be then exactly ?

Working with Bootstrap, you can work with the data-bs-toggle="dropdown" attribute to expand/collapse the dropdown without the manipulation from Angular (method).
<a class="nav-link nav-profile d-flex align-items-center pe-0 " href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    ... 
</a>

Make sure that you imported the Bootstrap Bundle or Bootstrap + Popper.JS as discussed in Bootstrap 5 dropdown is not working on Angular 12.
Demo @ StackBlitz

ok bro thank u , i'll try it , i'll give u updates if anything happened

take a bow , it worked , thank u for ur help , i really appreciate it
